# Why can I not accept an answer?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I'm trying to accept an answer to a question I asked ([specifically this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27632/what-are-common-pitfalls-of-cloud-development-that-you-have-run-into)) and as far as I can tell it just isn't working- I get the "hand" pointer when I mouseover the tick but clicking on it has no clear effect.

I'm using IE8 at the moment. I'll try it in a proper browser later, but it seems to me one should be able to use the site even in Exploder.

Comment: I've tried to repro this unsuccessfully in both IE8 and its "Compatibility View" (IE7 emulation).  I'm guessing you're not seeing any network traffic between yourself and the site when clicking?

Comment: I checked with Fiddler. Today it works. Absolutely no idea what is different. Something transient going on with my browser state somewhere I guess. No idea what but I guess it must have been inhibiting the JavaScript on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I can't repro this -- I am able to accept an answer in IE8 just fine.

Maybe clear the browser cache?

Comment: Odd. I can accept and unaccept this answer without a problem. Also noticed that the answer I wanted to accept is one I had already upvoted but I can upvote this one and still accept it whereas the one linked above I can't.

Comment: Hold on a second... is this because I tried to accept an answer that wasn't from you ;)

Comment: Looking at it in the IE Javascript debugger, a whole lot of stuff is going on but it's in compressed JQuery type code and without dedicating a lot of time to it I don't know what variables a, b, c, d et al are up to.